# How To access method inside WebChromeClient?

Tags: java, android, webchromeclient

i am setting up a method in webchromeclient like this:

```
web1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onHideCustomView(){}
});
```

Then i want to create javascriptinterface to call onHideCustomView().
How can I call method which is inside the webchromeclient? i tried to get the method name using stacktrace but it only shows anonymous inner class "MainActivity$34.onHideCustomView()"

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a private class inside your class which extends `WebChromeClient` For example:

```
class YourCustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
```

Inside this class override the method, like below,

```
@Override
    public void onHideCustomView()
    { 
       //add your code when onHideCustomView is called 
    }
```

And just sets your `web1` with this custom chrome client.

```
web1.setWebChromeClient(YourCustomWebChromeClient);
```

Using `YourCustomWebChromeClient` object, now you can call `onHideCustomView` method.

Comment: if i have multiple: web1.setWebChromeClient(YourCustomWebChromeClient); web2.setWebChromeClient(YourCustomWebChromeClient); web3.setWebChromeClient(YourCustomWebChromeClient);    how can i call the web2 onHideCustomView?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide an interface for js, use this code:

```
public class MyJsInterface {
    private WeakReference<View> myTargetView;

    public MyJsInterfaceImpl(View view){
        this.myTargetView = new  WeakReference<>(view);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onHideCustomView(){
        if(myTargetView.get() != null){
            myTargetView.get().post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public run(){
                    myTargetView.get().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

webview.addJavascriptInterface(myJsInterface, "lovelyAndroid");
```

in js:

```
window.lovelyAndroid.onHideCustomView()
```

don't forget to enable js in webview:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```